# How to use services in MEAN stack?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

**Problem**

I am working with a large amount of data and when passing between components with the RouterLink it calls back to the database through the services to MongoDB, so it is a bad experience for the user

**Code**

--Institution.component.ts

```
 listInstitutions: Institution[] = [];

getInstitution() {
    this._institutionService.getInstitutions().subscribe((data) => {
      this.listInstitutions = data;
    });
  }
```

--Institution.service.ts

```
 getInstitutions(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
```

**Solution**

In order for it to pass between components through the Link router without reloading the getInstitutions() method, I have created everything in the service, including the data list, that is, everything from institution.component.ts to institution.service.ts and I only call the list that is in the service for my crud in the institution.component.html

_serviceInstitution.listIntitutions

With this I can now navigate between the components so that the database method is not called every time.

**Conclusion**

Is it an efficient way to do it? What are your problems? Is it okay to do it? , I have seen that in other places they use only the syntax said at the beginning. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to cache the values, do this only if you are sure that the API needs to be executed only once, in your application. Below I am using `AsyncSubject` for caching the response.

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AsyncSubject, Observable, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const API_URL = 'https://reqres.in';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApiService implements OnDestroy {
  asyncSubject: AsyncSubject<any>;
  subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public get(url): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + '/api/' + url).pipe(map((res) => res));
  }

  public getAsync(url): Observable<any> {
    if (!this.asyncSubject) {
      this.asyncSubject = new AsyncSubject();
      this.subscription.add(
        this.http.get(API_URL + '/api/' + url).subscribe((response) => {
          this.asyncSubject.next(response);
          this.asyncSubject.complete();
        })
      );
    }
    return this.asyncSubject.asObservable();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
// /api/users
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-api-call-xq3vdu)

reference [here](https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs/subjects/async-subject)

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it doesn't work for me, when entering the component with the routerLink the method this.getInstitution(); the component is refreshed....

Comment: @MichaelLedesma is your issue resolved?

Comment: the truth was not what I wanted but I already figured out how to do it, giving a push to the model from the front and placing observables as services and subscribing

Comment: Thank you very much, but I will still leave open waiting for other ways to do it